# Что такое МОД2

Tags: c++

Нужно найти значение выражения
`(Ац ИЛИ Вц) МОД2 (Ац ИЛИ Сц)`,
где Ац, Вц и Сц - целые части значений переменных a, b, c, 
операции И, ИЛИ, МОД2 (сложение по модулю 2) - поразрядные.
Не могу разобраться, что такое МОД2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это xor. В с/с++ есть оператор `^`.

```
(Ац ИЛИ Вц) МОД2 (Ац ИЛИ Сц)

(a | b) ^ (a | c)
```

Посмотреть [больше](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a+%7C+b%29+%5E+%28a+%7C+c%29).

Comment: А почему он называется "сложение по модулю"?

Comment: Потому что это сложение по модулю. Я в комментариях дискретную математику не расскажу:) [Почитайте](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a+%7C+b%29+%5E+%28a+%7C+c%29) немного самостоятельно.